# How to make Nuxt 3 correctly build SSG pages + dynamic API routes?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3

I'm building a site which uses only a combination of statically generated pages and JSON API routes, with no runtime SSR of templates. I would like Nuxt to build it accordingly:

- Routes under `/api` should be handled by a runtime server
- Every other route should be prerendered at build time

However, I can't figure out how to configure Nuxt to do this particular combination:

- Running `nuxt build` generates the api routes correctly, but doesn't prerender the pages
- Running `nuxt generate` prerenders the pages, but doesn't output a server for the api routes

I'm on the nitro `cloudflare` preset. I've tried various combinations of `routeRules`, but I can't figure out how to get the behavior I want. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was eventually able to get this working by configuring the underlying Nitro build in my `nuxt.config.ts`!

```
nitro: {
  prerender: {
    crawlLinks: true,
    routes: ['/'],
    ignore: ["/api"]
  }
},
```

This causes `nuxt build` to crawl all links down from the front page and prerender, while still correctly outputting a `worker.js` to handle the `/api` routes at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is put your `<div>` in the template in `<clientOnly>` and use lazyfetch for getting data.

for generate,first make your _slug page and set in your generate. for example if you have 3 pages on blog route in nuxt 2 you should do this. I think in nuxt 3 is similar.

in nuxt.config

```
generate:{
 dir: 'your directory of generate',
 routes:()=>{
  return[
   '/blog/blog1_page',
   '/blog/blog2_page',
   '...'
  ]
}
```

Comment: That sounds more like an SPA-- I want to statically generate multiple pages

Comment: I updated the answer. I hope it helps you.